# Simple Meteor (1.7.0.5) publish/subscribe to collection doesnt work

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish, subscribe

I have a collection in Mongo containing 2 items, I see them when autopublish is enabled. But when I disable autopublish, and when I add publish and subscribe code, it doesnt work anymore.

This is the first time i'm using Meteor version 1.7.0.5, before I always used 1.6 and I never had any issue with publish/subscribe ...

It is such a simple test, but what am I doing wrong ? I have the following code and files:

/client/xxx/xxx.html

```html
<template name="XxxTemplate">
    {{#each xxxHelper}}
    {{name}}<br>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

/collections/_Xxxx.js

```js
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema'

XxxCollection = new Meteor.Collection('XxxCollection');
XxxCollectionSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name"
    }
});
XxxCollection.attachSchema(XxxCollectionSchema);
```

/server/mongodb/publish.js

```js
Meteor.publish('XxxCollection', function () {
    return XxxCollection.find();
});
```

/client/xxx/xxx.js

```js
Template.XxxTemplate.onCreated(function() {
   Meteor.subscribe('XxxCollection');
});

Template.XxxTemplate.helpers({
    xxxHelper: function() {
        console.log("xxxHelper is called");
        var r = XxxCollection.find();
        console.log(r);
        return r;
    }
});
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{  
   "name":"TestApp",
   "private":true,
   "scripts":{  
      "start":"meteor run",
      "test":"...",
      "test-app":"...",
      "visualize":"meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer"
   },
   "dependencies":{  
      "@babel/runtime":"7.0.0-beta.55",
      "meteor-node-stubs":"^0.4.1",
      "simpl-schema":"^1.5.3"
   },
   "meteor":{  
      "mainModule":{  
         "client":"client/main.js",
         "server":"server/main.js"
      },
      "testModule":"tests/main.js"
   }
}
```

Comment: **I replicated your code and it's working fine**. Can you show us your `package.json` file ? Because since Meteor 1.7 there is a difference with how code is loaded.

Comment: thx for helping, my package.json file looks like this:  `{ "name": "TestApp",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "...",
    "test-app": "...",
    "visualize": "meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1",
    "simpl-schema": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "meteor": {
    "mainModule": {
      "client": "client/main.js",
      "server": "server/main.js"
    },
    "testModule": "tests/main.js"
  }
}`

Comment: @TomTem please edit your question and add the package.js entries there instead of putting them into a comment. Comments are usually there for talking, while your question area provides much better options to format and display code snippets than comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your project to work like in Meteor 1.6, you **have to remove the mainModule property from your package.json**.

**Explanation**:

Since **Meteor 1.7**, new projects have **lazy loading enabled by default** even outside the imports/ folder.

This is made by the property mainModule inside the package.json file :

```
"mainModule": {
  "client": "client/main.js",
  "server": "server/main.js"
},
```

If you want to use the eager loading (disable the lazy loading) **you have to remove the mainModule property from your package.json**.

In your case, the problem doesn't come from the autopublish, but from the lazy loading being enabled.

---

More resources here:

- *Meteor Guide to use the ES Modules:* https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#es2015-modules
- *Meteor Blog Post about 1.7:* https://blog.meteor.com/meteor-1-7-and-the-evergreen-dream-a8c1270b0901

Comment: omg that was it, thx! I removed the entire "meteor":{...} section and it works now.